# RMStore openssl/pkcs7.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode8, rmstore

I am trying to use RMStore in order to verify the receipts locally. I have followed the instructions in order to add static ssl libaries: https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/wiki/Receipt-verification#adding-openssl

Transfered the 4 files, i downloaded binaries and headers.

1.In Build Phases, add libssl.a and libcrypto.a to Link Binary With Libraries.

2.In Build Settings, add the headers folder to the Header Search Paths.

At the second step above is where the issue exists(i think). At the moment the header search path is

```
   $(PROJECT_DIR)/RMStore/Optional/openssl-1.0.1e/include
```

and the library search path:

```
   $(PROJECT_DIR)/RMStore/Optional/openssl-1.0.1e/lib
```

Am i supposed to replace "RMStore" with my projects name? Where am i going wrong?

Also a side question(but relevant to openssl), when submitting to the App store, what do i answer to the "Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?" question? Do i have to apply for confirmation approval?

Comment: Any Luck here ?

Comment: Yes, i found a workaround see the answer i posted.. Let me know if it works for you.. I still have trouble in parsing the receipt though :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I separately installed openSSL via cocoapods and that solved my issue.
I used this one: https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenSSL-Universal

but there are others available as well...

Answer (score 3):

If you add folder OpenSSL to your project, and all files for OpenSSL will be there.
Add OpenSSL folder to the top of your Project (not in subfolders)

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/OpenSSL/include    -   Header Search Paths
$(PROJECT_DIR)/OpenSSL/lib        -   Library Search Paths`
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `$(PROJECT_DIR)/OpenSSL/include` to *Header Search Paths* of *Build Settings*

OpenSSL Folder must be in root directory

[image]